# Kubernetes how do you create persistent volume on AWS Elastic Block Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, metabase

I try to create persistent volume with AWS Elastic Block Store, so whenever I deployed a metabase pods no need to worry to losing all initial data I've settled up.

Here is **Deployment** yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: metabase
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: metabase
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: metabase
        image: metabase/metabase
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/metabase-ebs"
          name: metabase-volume
      volumes:
        - name: metabase-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: metabase-pvc
```

My **Persistent Volume Claim** yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: metabase-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: metabase-pv
```

My **Persistent Volume** yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: "metabase-pv"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: MY-EBS-VOLUME-ID
    fsType: ext4
```

How I test if my persistent volume is right or not:

1. I destroy my pods after I set initial metabase setup
2. Recreate pods

If there is no need to do the initial setup again. Then it works, if not then it fails.

Is my test scenario wrong? Or how do you manage to work with Persistent volume using AWS EBS?

Thanks in advance :)

***UPDATE***

Sorry, silly me I forget to mention the issue Im facing :bow:

The issue is:

Whenever I recreate pods after I do the initial setup, I have to do the initial setup again. So I assumed the Persistent Volume not working :(

Comment: Hi - your assumtions are right - just make sure to keep the PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim untouched once they're configured and assigned. But what's your actual issue/question?

Comment: @pagid Hi, updated my question, sorry.